# Why isn't this while statement not working in the catch block

Tags: javascript, while-loop, try-catch-finally

I have a simple a HTML document with a script tag, I'm messing around with a try catch and can't get the while statement in the catch block to work. The try and catch simply runs as if the while block isn't there.

```js
try {
  let age = prompt("age?")
  if (age <= 0 || age >= 120) {
    throw new Error("Something Happened!")
  }
} catch (e) {
  let state = true;
  while (state) {
    age = prompt("age?");
    if (age > 0 || age < 120) {
      state = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(age>0|| age<120){` All numbers are either greater than `0` OR less than `120`. You need `&&` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`age>0|| age<120` is always true, so you always set `state` to `false` and quit the loop after one iteration.

You should use `&&` instead of `||` for that condition, then it will only be true for numbers that are both greater than 0 *and* less than 120.